# What is the VC Dimension of a Naive Bayes Classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, statistical-learning, vc-dimension

How do you calculate the VC dimension of a Naive Bayes classifier with say K features?

Answer (score 2):

(1) shows that the VC dimension of a Naive Bayes classifier is linearly
proportional to the number of parameters.

---

(1) Roth, Dan. "[Learning in natural language](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=17168928115651740174&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)." Urbana 51 (1999): 61801.